# Creating Profile UI in Storyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard

I am trying to create a profile UI in storyboard, but I stuck with a problem. I need to create "header" like in a twitter app profile, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to put an imageView in prototype cell, but it starting scrolling with the whole tableView (for example, when I am trying to scroll up there an empty space in the top).

[Click here to see necessary UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkPs2.png)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**!!! SOLUTION**

I found the best solution that fits me. I am away from xCode, so I tried to illustrate it in Sketch.

[Click here to see the scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNr6V.png)

You need to setup a containerView inside your ViewController. There will be tableView embed in your containerView. Now, you need to setup your first prototype cell with the height of imageView inside your ViewController. Then, all what you need are couple lines of code :)

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IDOfYourFirstPrototypeCell") as UITableViewCell!
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
return cell
```

and in your viewDidLoad function:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Also, if I doesn't mistake you need to remove background of ContainerView.

In your ViewController's viewDidLoad function:

```
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Sorry, if there some grammar mistakes in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

You should to get out your profile view from tableView. Try this UI scheme

[image]

Comment: I want "header" to be on the top, not scroll with whole tableView

Comment: What views will header have?

Comment: Header will be an imageView.

https://postimg.org/image/upvvegu3v/

This is what exactly happening when I am start scrolling down, but I need to stay it on the top.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is my current scheme and it's doesn't work :(

Comment: Maybe, I made a mistake in my previous comments. I need this header to be on the top of ViewController (not on the top of the screen)

Comment: On image you can see UIViewController. Can you tell me the difference between the top of the ViewController and the top of the screen?

Comment: Top of the screen - it's what you see on your phone screen wherever you scroll - it will be always on the top (like navigation bar, it's scrolling with your content), but the top of the ViewController is a simple object, which will be there whatever you do

Comment: Can you extract your realisation of this view controller and send here?